# Texture Paint Mode Paint on 3D Model

Tags: texture-painting

I'm starting to learn texture paint mode and I have the hang of it for the most part.  But I'm getting inconsistent results.

Before I was able to paint directly on the model (I know it isn't really doing so and is actually painting on the UV image).

But now when I click on the model with any brush it doesn't paint at all, which isn't a huge deal but I'd like to know why it stopped working.

It still works with the "Mask" brush, but none of the others will work.

Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: The little cube in the header with one face that has red squares on it, is this enabled? With this on only verts selected in edit mode can be painted on.

Comment: could you please share your file?

Comment: @sambler yes that was it!  so simple, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When texture painting, there is an option to restrict painting to faces that have been selected in edit mode.

[image: face selection masking]

If this is something you want to use, you need to go into edit mode and alter your selection to adjust the areas you can paint on.